# get all url from a reseach in a website and connect to these URLs using JSOUP

Tags: parsing, web, jsoup

I search all the car offers from a website. I have more than 70 000 car offers. In one page, i can only see 30 car offers.

```
Page 1 URL : https://caroffer.com/offer/   => I can see 30 car offers
Page 2 URL : https://caroffer.com/offer/p-2  => I can see 30 car offers
Page 3 URL : https://caroffer.com/offer/p-3 => I can see 30 car offers
.
.
.
Page n URL : https://caroffer.com/offer/p-n => I can see 30 car offers
```

1. How to I get all the 70 000 car offer ?
2. How to I connect to all this offers via JSOUP?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not very clear. Can you elaborate what you have tried and what problem you are facing? Do you expect more car offers on each page? Do you have trouble formulating the loop construct that queries all the URLs? Here are possible hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390741/jsoup-get-dynamically-generated-html/22400976#22400976, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422968/not-able-to-parse-complete-html-of-a-url-using-jsoup/19467985#19467985

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. OK, I found the solution                                                     for (i <-1 to nbResult) {  https://caroffer.com/offer/p-i}                                                      And, For the number of result in one page                                                                                                                     (nbResult, I found also a solution)